# Reading words of a .txt file not working C

Tags: c, file, numbers

I wanted to search for specific words in a .txt file.

**For example the file includes "Jon Miller, Andy Miller, Apu McDawn" 
And I want to search for "Miller" in this file how often it occures.
then it should show me the number (num) "2"**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    int num =0;
    char word[100];
    char *string;

    FILE *in_file = fopen("test.txt", "r"); //reading the words

    if (in_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Dataerror\n"); //if word not found
        exit(-1);
    }

    else {
        scanf("%s", word);
        printf("%s\n", word);

        while(!feof(in_file))//search for the word

        {
            fscanf(in_file,"%s", string);
            if(!strcmp(string , word))//if hit a word
            num++;
        }

        printf( "%d Hit \n" ,num );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you should allocate space for the string 'char* string'. You try to read just into the pointer. Second, fscanf reads the string with ',' sign.

Comment: You can use `strncmp`.

Comment: Please, describe what happens now. How many hits does it show? There is no question in your message.

Comment: can you post a sample of your file's content?

Comment: Use the `fscanf` as the condition of the loop and add a space before a comma

Comment: Use `strstr` instead of `strcmp`.

Comment: thats my files content http://abload.de/image.php?img=unbenannt91qvu.jpg

Comment: @Crannyman Append your post with a sample of file contents here and not as a picture via an off-site link.

Comment: @Crannyman , What's your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory for `string`. Change

```
char *string;
```

To

```
char string[100];
```

Or allocate memory dynamically

```
string=malloc(100);
```

And free it after its use using

```
free(string);
```

Also change

```
while(!feof(in_file))
```

To

```
while(fscanf(in_file,"%s", string))
```

And remove the `fscanf` inside the body of this loop. Read [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) to know why I've made that change. And include `string.h` in your program.

Comment: Thx so much Cool Guy but there's still a problem now. When I search for 2 Words such as "Trude Mustermann" it won't search for Musterman only for Trude. Now how to fix that :( I owe you!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped. Change the **first** `scanf` to `scanf("%[^\n]",word);getchar();`

Comment: for some reason it count's 0 when searching for Trude Mustermann

Comment: Two reasons. 1. You text file does not contain it because there is no space between it. 2. Your `fscanf` scans word by word.

Comment: Which means that you need to get the whole line using `fgets` and then use `strstr` instead of `strcmp`. Read up on it

Comment: You can ask a new question about it if you still did not get it.

Comment: yea I did not get it. I've asked new one.

Answer (score -2):

My friend i have just changed the function strcmp to strncmp.
& it works.
Both these functions compare two strings. strcmp() compares the entire string down to the end, while strncmp() only compares the first n characters of the strings.nction strcmp to strncmp.

It's a little funky what they return. Basically it's a difference of the strings, so if the strings are the same, it'll return zero (since the difference is zero). It'll return non-zero if the strings differ; basically it will find the first mismatched character and return less-than zero if that character in string is less than the corresponding character in word. It'll return greater-than zero if that character in string is greater than that in word.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {   
int num =0;

char word[100];

char *string;

FILE *in_file = fopen("ser.txt", "r"); //reading the words

if (in_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Dataerror\n"); //if word not found
    exit(-1);
}

else {
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("%s\n", word);

    while(!feof(in_file))//search for the word

    {
        fscanf(in_file,"%s", string);
        if(!strncmp(string , word))//if hit a word
        num++;
    }

    printf( "%d Hit \n" ,num );
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: U r missing one argument. `strncmp` has 3 args.

Comment: You need `string.h` to use `strncmp` which has 3 arguments.